# How can I init a class with string array?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this script that get the properties by names from a shader :
At the bottom I'm changing one of the properties values by giving the property name: "Vector1_570450D5"

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.PlayerLoop;

public class ChangeShaders : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Material material;
    public float duration = 1;

    private List<string> propertiesNames = new List<string>();

    private void Awake()
    {
        material = GetComponent<Renderer>().material;

        var propertiesCount = ShaderUtil.GetPropertyCount(material.shader);

        for(int i = 0; i < propertiesCount; i++)
        {
            propertiesNames.Add(ShaderUtil.GetPropertyName(material.shader, i));
        }    
    }

    void Update()
    {
        var currentValue = Mathf.Lerp(-1, 1, Mathf.PingPong(Time.time / duration, 1));
        material.SetFloat("Vector1_570450D5", currentValue);
    }
}
```

but instead typing manual the property name I want to create a class for each property name so I will be able to type inside the SetFloat something like :

```
material.SetFloat(myProperties.Vector1_570450D5, currentValue);
```

[image: Properties]

In this case there are 5 properties so I want to be able to do :

```
material.SetFloat(myProperties.Vector1_570450D5, currentValue);
```

Or

```
material.SetFloat(myProperties.Color_50147CDB, currentValue);
```

So I thought to make this script with the attribute executeallways to create a editor script only for getting the properties and then to use the properties in this mono script like in the examples I gave.

Answer (score 1):

Just to your title: You have a `List<string>`, not an array ;)

---

Before filling it with values you would need to initialize it. You can also do that together with the field declaration:

```
public List<string> names = new List<string>();
```

---

Even simpler would then be a proper constructor and e.g. using

```
public class MyClass
{
    public List<string> names = new List<string>();

    public MyClass(List<string> initialNames)
    {
        // This creates a new List<string> copying all elements of initialNames
        names = new List<string>(initialNames);
    }
}
```

And then use it like

```
var myClass = new MyClass(names);
```

---

If I understand correct you are further looking for a property like e.g.

```
public string this[int index] => names[i];
```

which would allow you to access a specific entry directly via

```
myClass[i];
```

instead of

```
myClass.names[i];
```

Comment: This is working fine. If I wanted to make something more complicated for example that I will type myClass.1 or myClass.2  where the number 1 and 2 extracted from the 'i' variable.  i.ToString() is the names for example "1" "2" "3" so to create properties of the numbers if I type myClass it will show the numbers as properties like myClass.1 myClass.2 so I can use the numbers later in other scripts as int's or convert them to strings. I don't want to loop over the List myClass.names but to get directly access to the properties.

Comment: @bendivonim What about using a `Dictionary<int, string>` then? Or do you mean a property like `public int this[int index] => names[i];`  so you could use `myClass[i]` instead of `myClass.names[i];` ?

Comment: The second public int this[int index] => names[i];

Comment: How do I use this in the for loop in the awake ? public string this[int index] => names[i]; getting errors.

Comment: Nope this would be a property of `MyClass` and you wouldn't use it in the loop actually ... Maybe I still didn't fully understand your entire use case / goal :)

Comment: I didn't explain it all or at all. This question is relevant to my earlier question with the shader properties. Should I edit this question to add and explain what I want ?

Comment: Sorry for the mess I had to edit and change my question body to explain better what I want to do.